# Problema cálculo média entre int e float

Tags: c, struct, tipagem, float

Estou com um problema em um cálculo de média.

Tenho uma struct com 3 campos. Os que estou querendo a média são quantidade de produtos e o valor unitário. Preciso fazer a média entre todos os produtos e seus preços. Porém, quando tenho valores unitários com 0,50 por exemplo, ele não soma no cálculo e faz a média somente dos valores que começam com no mínimo 1,00. A quantidade é int e o valor é float.

A soma e a média é a seguinte:

```
int x;
double soma=0,media;
for(x=0;x<n;x++)
{
    soma+=((prod[x].PRECO)*(prod[x].QTDE));
}
media=soma/n;
printf("\n\n\nA media de valor entre todos os produtos estocados eh: %.2lf", media);
```

Comment: Isso dá a impressão de ter havido erro no input. Como é que recolhes as informações para cada elemento do array? Lembra-te que uma variável de tipo `int` não pode ter valores com virgula flutuante (tipo `0.5`).

Comment: mostre como você inicializa `prod[x].PRECO`

Comment: Já percebi o erro. Realmente estava fazendo a entrada de dados utilizando ',' ao invés de '.' na quebra do float.

Comment: Qual função poderia utilizar para garantir a entrada correta, mesmo o usuário utilizando ',' e não dar problemas no programa?

Comment: Para garantir entrada correcta usa `fgets()` e `strtol()` (e/ou `strtod()`) com validações!!

Answer (score 1):

A linguagem C exige conversões explicitas entre float, double, int e semelhantes. Na linha:

```
media=soma/n;
```

escreva

```
media = soma / ((double) n);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Vinícius, pra você realizar a entrada correta eu te recomendaria usar a feature de Entrada Formatada do `scanf`

Quando você lê do teclado, ele atribui pra uma string que depois você usa usa `strtol()` para transformar em `double`

```
char string[30]; //exemplo de uso
double num;
scanf("%[0-9/-,.]", &leitura); // Vai permitir apenas numeros, `-`, `,` e `.`
num = strtol(string);
```

Acho que vai resolver o problema.